# Openwrt on Airlive AirMax5

Tags: router, openwrt

We are tyring to install openwrt firmware on Airlive Airmax5 which is running DD-WRT by default. Can anyone please help me, how to install openwrt on wireless router.

Waiting for reply.
Caterpillar...

Answer (score 0):

Since its running DD-wrt the change to openwrt shouldn't be hard at all. Download the appropriate firmware for your hardware from openwrt and then in the dd-wrt web interface to upgrade.

If that doesn't work go the tftp route. The steps will be similar.
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation